# Сброка QT-приложения linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: c++, ubuntu, qt

Пытаюсь собрать приложение, компилятор выдает ошибку:

```
:-1: error: cannot find -lGL
```

Вот что нашел:

```
~$ apt-file search libGL.so
fglrx: /usr/lib/fglrx/libGL.so
fglrx: /usr/lib/fglrx/libGL.so.1
fglrx: /usr/lib/fglrx/libGL.so.1.2
fglrx: /usr/lib32/fglrx/libGL.so.1.2
fglrx-updates: /usr/lib/fglrx/libGL.so
fglrx-updates: /usr/lib/fglrx/libGL.so.1
fglrx-updates: /usr/lib/fglrx/libGL.so.1.2
fglrx-updates: /usr/lib32/fglrx/libGL.so.1.2
libgl1-mesa-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
libgl1-mesa-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so
libgl1-mesa-glx: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
libgl1-mesa-glx: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
libgl1-mesa-glx-dbg: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
nvidia-173: /usr/lib/nvidia-173/libGL.so
nvidia-173: /usr/lib/nvidia-173/libGL.so.1
nvidia-173: /usr/lib/nvidia-173/libGL.so.173.14.39
nvidia-173: /usr/lib32/nvidia-173/libGL.so
nvidia-173: /usr/lib32/nvidia-173/libGL.so.1
nvidia-173: /usr/lib32/nvidia-173/libGL.so.173.14.39
nvidia-304: /usr/lib/nvidia-304/libGL.so
nvidia-304: /usr/lib/nvidia-304/libGL.so.1
nvidia-304: /usr/lib/nvidia-304/libGL.so.304.117
nvidia-304: /usr/lib/nvidia-304/libGL.so.304.125
nvidia-304: /usr/lib32/nvidia-304/libGL.so
nvidia-304: /usr/lib32/nvidia-304/libGL.so.1
nvidia-304: /usr/lib32/nvidia-304/libGL.so.304.117
nvidia-304: /usr/lib32/nvidia-304/libGL.so.304.125
nvidia-304-updates: /usr/lib/nvidia-304-updates/libGL.so
nvidia-304-updates: /usr/lib/nvidia-304-updates/libGL.so.1
nvidia-304-updates: /usr/lib/nvidia-304-updates/libGL.so.304.117
nvidia-304-updates: /usr/lib/nvidia-304-updates/libGL.so.304.125
nvidia-304-updates: /usr/lib32/nvidia-304-updates/libGL.so
nvidia-304-updates: /usr/lib32/nvidia-304-updates/libGL.so.1
nvidia-304-updates: /usr/lib32/nvidia-304-updates/libGL.so.304.117
nvidia-304-updates: /usr/lib32/nvidia-304-updates/libGL.so.304.125
nvidia-331: /usr/lib/nvidia-331/libGL.so
nvidia-331: /usr/lib/nvidia-331/libGL.so.1
nvidia-331: /usr/lib/nvidia-331/libGL.so.331.113
nvidia-331: /usr/lib/nvidia-331/libGL.so.331.38
nvidia-331: /usr/lib32/nvidia-331/libGL.so
nvidia-331: /usr/lib32/nvidia-331/libGL.so.1
nvidia-331: /usr/lib32/nvidia-331/libGL.so.331.113
nvidia-331: /usr/lib32/nvidia-331/libGL.so.331.38
nvidia-331-updates: /usr/lib/nvidia-331-updates/libGL.so
nvidia-331-updates: /usr/lib/nvidia-331-updates/libGL.so.1
nvidia-331-updates: /usr/lib/nvidia-331-updates/libGL.so.331.113
nvidia-331-updates: /usr/lib/nvidia-331-updates/libGL.so.331.38
nvidia-331-updates: /usr/lib32/nvidia-331-updates/libGL.so
nvidia-331-updates: /usr/lib32/nvidia-331-updates/libGL.so.1
nvidia-331-updates: /usr/lib32/nvidia-331-updates/libGL.so.331.113
nvidia-331-updates: /usr/lib32/nvidia-331-updates/libGL.so.331.38
primus-libs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/primus/libGL.so.1
```

что делать дальше не знаю.

Comment: Попробуй установи пакет libglu1-mesa-dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не выдержал, переустановил операционную систему. Позже прочитал на qt-project.org:

```
sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev -y
```

> Tested with Qt5.3.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 and it solved the problem with missing -lGL.